# How to do jQuery DataTables server side data with Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, google-apps-script

DataTables works fine with GAS HTMLService when the data is provided on initial page load but better practice for GAS is to "Load data asynchronously, not in templates". Also server-side processing for DataTables provides a more responsive UI for large datatables. I am looking for a pattern that satisfies these recommendations. I am starting from an elementary DataTables example translated into GAS HTMLService Template model.

GS Code:

```
 function doGet() {
   Logger.log("Start");
   var start = new Date();
   // rt params
   // var rtParameters = getRunTimeParameters(request);
   // uses HtmlService to send page based on a template
   var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('chart');
   // prepare data for initial page

   Logger.log("TIME to return:"+ (new Date() -start));
   return temp.evaluate();
 }

  function include(filename) {
    // helper function to load html into template from sep files in project
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
  }
```

HTMLtemplate - chart

```
   ...
   <body>
   <h1>JQUERY  DataTables  Page  Generated in Google Apps Script </h1>
   <p>Includes sorting, paging and filtering by default.</p>
   <p>Entire data table loaded in one hit.</p>
   <div id="demo"></div>
   <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
   </body>
```

Javascript (with Datatable definition inline)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );
$('#example').dataTable( {
       "aaData": [
        /* Reduced data set */
        [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 4.0", "Win 95+", 4, "X" ],
        [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 5.0", "Win 95+", 5, "C" ],
        [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 5.5", "Win 95+", 5.5, "A" ],
        [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 6.0", "Win 98+", 6, "A" ],
        [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 7.0", "Win XP SP2+", 7, "A" ],
        [ "Gecko", "Firefox 1.5", "Win 98+ / OSX.2+", 1.8, "A" ],
        [ "Gecko", "Firefox 2", "Win 98+ / OSX.2+", 1.8, "A" ],
        [ "Gecko", "Firefox 3", "Win 2k+ / OSX.3+", 1.9, "A" ],
        [ "Webkit", "Safari 1.2", "OSX.3", 125.5, "A" ],
        [ "Webkit", "Safari 1.3", "OSX.3", 312.8, "A" ],
        [ "Webkit", "Safari 2.0", "OSX.4+", 419.3, "A" ],
        [ "Webkit", "Safari 3.0", "OSX.4+", 522.1, "A" ]
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "Engine" },
        { "sTitle": "Browser" },
        { "sTitle": "Platform" },
        { "sTitle": "Version", "sClass": "center" },
        { "sTitle": "Grade", "sClass": "center" }
    ]

} );
```

} );

Initial problem: how to load DataTable 'aaData' asynchronously per https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates

More generally: how to implement DataTAbles server-side processing with GAS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way: get all the data at once. like this

In GS Code add function

```
function getData(){
   var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YourSheetID').getSheetByName('YourSheetName').getDataRange().getValues();
   return data;
}
```

In HTMLtemlate:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var runner = google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure);
        runner.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getData();
    });
    var onSuccess = function(data){
        var aDataSet = data.slice(1);  // all except header


        var head = [];  // headers
        data[0].forEach(function(e){
            head.push({'sTitle': e});
        });

        $('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "aaData": aDataSet,
            "aoColumns": head
        });
    }
    var onFailure = function(err){
        alert(err.message);
    }
    </script>
```

See my [example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw2f0GDJHS8zeLEEqABpaoHSta2IczNzgAWj_mYnQOwFharC4b2/exec) for [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgOO-4t6UMZFdEx6SUJBalRhalk5Rkd3blE2a1h0RlE#gid=0) ([source code](https://script.google.com/d/1mrWFhLGf1BRZ5_ObhCQwz0SPp-9kQObEX4eyojxqa7lySxcE7wgBfITb/edit))

**UPD:**
In order to implement server-side processing with GAS, you need to use ContentService (as REST server)
You will need to handle parameters such as iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength, iSortCol_0 etc.

```
doGet(e){
  var iSortCol_0 = e.parameter.iSortCol;
  ...
  etc.
```

see how it is [implemented on PHP + MySQL](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html)

To make it easier to do paging, order, limit and other operations, you can save all the data  in [ScriptDB](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#sorting__pagination), which already has a similar functions to query

*Sorry for my bad english =)*

Comment: Thank you so much. The key thing that was missing for me was how to handle parameters iDisplayStart etc. I prefer the clear separation that you get from the ContentService rather than htmlservice. Loading the data all at once provides a good solution for me now but I want to have a clear path for dealing with larger volumes of data.